# gdal_edit in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal

I am new of programming and I need help for it.
I would use `gdal_edit` to modify SRC of 300 hundred aerial photos, if I use this tool one by one work perfectly, but I would want to use it in a cycle in a python script to simplify and get faster my job.

This is the tool I used:

```
gdal_edit -a_srs EPSG:3004 "C:/Users/Laptop/Desktop/test/img.ecw"
```

While this is the python script in that I would use this tool:

```
import os, gdal

dir="C:/Users/Laptop/Desktop/test"
array=os.listdir(dir)
for e in array:
    if os.path.splitext(e)[1]==".ecw":
        print(e)
        gdal_edit -a_srs EPSG:3004 dir+e
```

How can I use `gdal_edit` in this code? 
I use OsGeo4W Shell that has gdal and python preinstallated.

Comment: One way is to create a string that matches exactly what you would type normally, then use subprocess.call(string) to execute it. You will need to import subprocess module. Also, I have noticed that it is best to create your string as a list, i.e. string = ['gdal_edit', '-a_srs', 'EPSG:3004', 'C:/Users/Laptop/Desktop/test/img.ecw']

Comment: Hi Jon, 
thank you for your post, I tried using your advice before in direct command: 

 import subprocess
 subprocess.call['gdal_edit', '-a_srs', 'EPSG:3004', 'C:/Users/SIGEO/Documents/Luca/temp/test/521142.ecw']

but this is been error answer:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Can you understand it?

Comment: If you're using the exact code you posted, you have to call subprocess.call with (), not with []. Break it up as I suggested in my first comment: string = ['gdal_edit'...etc] then subprocess.call(string). It's more readable, and, as you discovered, less prone to mistakes. If you want to use your one-liner, just wrap your list in (); i.e. subprocess.call(['gdal_edit', '-a_srs', 'EPSG:3004', 'C:/Users/SIGEO/Documents/Luca/temp/test/521142.ecw'])

Answer (score 4):

The gdal_edit program is written in Python. You can copy a few lines of its code into your loop over the names of files to modify. This approach will be much faster than executing gdal_edit in a subprocess because creating new processes and launching Python takes a significant amount of time.

Here's how it opens the dataset for editing: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_edit.py#L280.

Here's how it updates the dataset's spatial reference system: 
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_edit.py#L310-L319.

Comment: Links are broken now, due to migration